# Parse push notification crashs after the app is dismissed

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications

Yes, I know that Parse will shut down next year, but for some reason or another, I have to use it's features for now. What is going on, it's that the push notification part works fine when the app is active, or even in background, but if I dismiss the app, what means he's not running anymore, it crashes when my app receives a push notification. I searched a lot, and all the people is telling me to put the Parse.initialize(...) on Application instead of an Activity, what, actually I'm  doing. Any clue about what is wrong with my project?

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.package.parse" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.package.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.package.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:name=".app.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.urlshortener.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider16..."
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.CustomPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.package.parse" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:21159024005" />;

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here's my Application:

```
public class MyApp  extends Application {

private static MyApp instance;
public static PreferencesManager prefs;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;

 PreferencesManager.initializeInstance(context);
    prefs = PreferencesManager.getInstance();

    if(isLogged()) {
        doParseStuff();
    }
}

public void configureParse(){


    Parse.initialize(this, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("GCMSenderId", this.getString(R.string.google_app_id));
    installation.saveInBackground();

    registerParse();
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}

public static void registerParse() {
    final String channel = MyApp.getCurrentUser() != null &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(MyApp.getCurrentUser().getUsername()) ? MyApp.getCurrentUser().getUsername() : "";

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(channel) ){
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channel, new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                    MyApp.setParseConfigured(true);

            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    MultiDex.install(this);

}

public static boolean isLogged() {
    return prefs.getBoolean(Constants.SharedPreferences.IS_LOGGED);
}

public static void setLogged(boolean b) {
    prefs.setValue(Constants.SharedPreferences.IS_LOGGED, b);
}

public static boolean isParseConfigured() {
    return prefs.getBoolean(Constants.SharedPreferences.IS_PARSE_CONFIGURED);
}

public static void setParseConfigured(boolean b) {
    prefs.setValue(Constants.SharedPreferences.IS_PARSE_CONFIGURED, b);
}

public static void setCurrentUser(CurrentUser user){

    prefs.setValue(Constants.SharedPreferences.USER, JSONUtils.getJSONString(user));

    instance.doParseStuff();
}

private void doParseStuff(){

        if(!isParseConfigured()) {
            configureParse();
        }
}

public static CurrentUser getCurrentUser(){
    return (CurrentUser) JSONUtils.getJSONObject(prefs.getString(Constants.SharedPreferences.USER), CurrentUser.class);
}

}
```

And here's my CustomPushReceiver:

```
public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

private Intent parseIntent;

public CustomPushReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //   super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent == null)
        return;

    String data = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");

        parseIntent = intent;

        parsePushJson(context, notificationModel.getAlert());
}

@Override
protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
}


private void parsePushJson(Context context, String alert) {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    showNotificationMessage(context, "", alert, resultIntent);

}


private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

    intent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);

    }
}
```

And for the last the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2905)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
at com.parse.PushService.onCreate(PushService.java:230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2895)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**EDIT 1**

This is the code inside de PushService, line 230:

```
if (ParsePlugins.Android.get().applicationContext() == null) {
  PLog.e(TAG, "The Parse push service cannot start because Parse.initialize "
      + "has not yet been called. If you call Parse.initialize from "
      + "an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the "
      + "Application.onCreate. Be sure your Application class is registered "
      + "in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your "
      + "<application> tag.");
  stopSelf();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Which is line number 230 in `PushService `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I've just edited the question with the code.

Comment: Daniel means  `ParsePlugins.Android.get()` return `null`. change it as `if)ParsePlugins.Android.get() ! = null){ ... your code here}`

Comment: The problem is that this code it's inside the parse lib, I can't change the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's caused just in the last released parse lib version, so I downgraded from `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'` to compile `'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'`  and now it's solved. Also, I had to remove the `installation.put("GCMSenderId", this.getString(R.string.google_app_id));` part to receive the notifications when app is dead.